# How can I drop iPhone 4 support in an update

Tags: ios, xcode

My app supports iPhone 4.
However, in the next major update I plan to add features that require better hardware (iPhone 4S and above). If I attempt to exclude iPhone 4 by adding requirements in `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`, Apple rejects the app during submission, citing that I cannot drop support for existing devices that can run the app.

iPhone 4 supports up to iOS 7, so even if I drop iOS6, I cannot exclude the device. Do I have any good options?

Comment: AFAIK the only way you can drop devices is to drop OS versions. You can't specifically say that a device can't run your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "`bluetooth-le*`” for UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities.

Here you can find a compatibility matrix… is not complete… but… http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/10/30/uirequireddevicecapabilities-and-device-compatibility-matrix

Comment: Yes I understand that. But as I said Apple won't allow it.

Comment: @Plenilune, Apple usually allows to specify the required hardwares for your application via `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`. you can read more about here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1397/_index.html